# Audio stream is not playing in react front end

Tags: reactjs, websocket, backend, esp32

I've have been working on a project where I am taking an input audio stream from esp32 device to my node backend server using websockets. I am getting the audio data in pcm format and sending this audio stream to my react frontend.
Even though I am getting the exact audio data in front end, it is still not playing the audio.
I am using pcm-player npm package to play the audio. There are no console errors not any data losses, I can't able to figure out what's going on.
My backend code look like this.

```
const http = require("http");
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("Hello, world!");
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

let audioData = [];
let clientMap = new Map();

wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
  console.log("Client connected");
  clientMap.set(ws, {});

  ws.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log(wss.clients);
    audioData.push(data);
    sendAudioData();
  });

  ws.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
    audioData = [];
  });
});

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 5000");
});

function sendAudioData() {
  if (audioData.length > 0) {
    // broadcasting the audio Data to all clients
    wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
      if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        client.send(audioData.join(""));
      }
    });
    audioData.length = 0;
  }
}
```

front end code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState(null);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [ws, setWs] = useState(null);
  let audioData = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000");

    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log("WebSocket connected");
    };

    ws.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log("getting data from server", event.data);
      audioData.push(event.data);
    };

    ws.onclose = () => {
      console.log("WebSocket disconnected");
      audioData.length = 0;
    };

    setWs(ws);

    return () => {
      ws.close();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (player && isPlaying) {
      player.play();
    } else if (player && !isPlaying) {
      player.pause();
    }
  }, [player, isPlaying]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ws && audioData.length > 0 && !player) {
      const pcmData = new Uint8Array(
        audioData
          .join("")
          .split("")
          .map((c) => c.charCodeAt(0))
      );
      const pcmPlayer = new PCMPlayer({
        encoding: "16bitInt",
        channels: 1,
        sampleRate: 44100,
      });
      pcmPlayer.feed(pcmData);
      setPlayer(pcmPlayer);
      setIsPlaying(true);
    }
  }, [ws, audioData, player]);

  const handlePlayClick = () => {
    console.log("playing");
    setIsPlaying(true);
  };

  const handleStopClick = () => {
    console.log("stopping");
    setIsPlaying(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        width: "100vw",
        height: "100vh",
        gap: "5px",
      }}
    >
      <button onClick={handlePlayClick}>Play</button>
      <button onClick={handleStopClick}>Stop</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried node-speaker module too, but seems like it is deprecated.